# How to efficiently handle the backend of popcat.click

Tags: mysql, database

I'm wondering how the makers of [popcat.click](https://popcat.click/) handles storing and retrieving the number of clicks per country with huge traffic and quick response times. From the network tab I see that clicks are batched and posted to the backend (instead of 1 post per click).

My theory so far is that the batched click data is dumped into a table, and a cron job is used to periodically get the number of clicks from this table to calculate and increment the country counter in a different table which can then be queried quickly.

I think multiple "dump" tables would have to be used to avoid data loss, clearing the data from one when it's processed and dumping data into the next.

Am I along the right lines? What other approaches/services could be used?